# Get max. index of 3D Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm new to php and don't get the trick ...

I have an multidimensional array which contains my mysql result.. now I want to write a function which builds html tables from the arraycontent.

I have no idea how I can get the max index value for my while loop to create the table content:

```
 print_r ($array) // gives 

 Array ( [0] => Array ( [idfahrer] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [idfahrer] => 2 ) )
```

I've read something about `max($array[])` but I was not able to make it run with this ... any ideas?

EDIT:

Sorry forgot the code I'm using for the array...

```
protected function GetData($query) {
        $link = $this->ConnectDB();
        $data = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link) . $query);
        if ($result) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

EDIT 2 :

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM users
returns

[id]---[name]---[age]

1----foo----30
2----bar----40
```

The array should look the following:

```
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1,[name] => "foo", [age] => 30 )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2,[name] => "bar", [age] => 40 )
```

now the function should see that there are two lines an create a html table like

```
|[id]---[name]---[age]
|
|1    |foo      |30 |
|2    |bar      |40 |
```

Comment: which index out of those multiple indexes do you want to return max of?

Comment: What do you _need_ the max index for?

Comment: `max($array[])` is definitely wrong. Try `max($array)` instead.

Comment: the first one ... "...[0] => Array..."

Comment: @CBroe i thought that i would need it as a counter ... the function should create an html table depending on the size an content of the array ... i think i cant find the corret words ... my english is not that good :-/

Comment: To just loop over the whole contents of an array you don't need a counter, just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: which key is used in the foreach loop then ? the first dimension or the other ones !? maybe i've got it completely wrong !?! :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    //do this
}
```

or if you want the max index for a reason other than iterating through the loop, try:

```
max(array_keys($array));
```

foreach > http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
max > http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php
array_keys > http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: thanks for the fast reply... will try to understand this "as" thing :-) i'm realy new to php ..sry

Comment: uhm ... so if i got it right... i would have to do it like this:

foreach ($data as $key => $val){
echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>" ;
...} !?

Comment: Don't worry, we all have to learn once. Basically, the way the `as` works is "take my array, and for every element, take the next `index` and assign it to `$key`; now take the next `value` and assign it to `$val`. Now that the variables have been declared, do what's inside of the loop." and does that for every element in the array. Also, don't forget your closing `</tr>` tag in the html.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multidimensional array, so you could loop or map to find out. Try this:

```
$max = max(array_map(function($v){ return $v['idfahrer']; }, $array));
```

But if you know that `idfahrer` corresponds to `i+1` then it's easier:

```
$max = count($array);
```

Did I understand the problem correctly?

Comment: thanks for the quick response... Problem is, that the "idfahrer" is not always the content of the key... the array is filled with the reults of an mysql query... so the key may also be sth else like "foo" or what ever ... maybe the EDIT2 in my question makes it better to understand...